# reset a select box graphically

Tags: jquery, forms, select, jquery-mobile

Using jquery mobile, I am trying to reset a form

I am using the following:

```
$('form').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

The value the select submits does reset to zero, but the image stays as it is.

Comment: Which image are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Create vs. refresh: An important distinction** 
> Note that there is an important difference between the create event and refresh method that
>   some widgets have. The create event is suited for enhancing raw markup
>   that contains one or more widgets. The refresh method should be used
>   on existing (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated
>   programmatically and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with `data-role=listview` attribute after page
>   creation, triggering create on a parent element of that list would
>   transform it into a listview styled widget. If more list items were
>   then programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method
>   would update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave
>   the existing list items untouched.

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> **Refreshing form elements** 
> In jQuery Mobile, some enhanced form controls are simply styled (inputs), but others are custom controls
>   (selects, sliders) built from, and kept in sync with, the native
>   control. To programmatically update a form control with JavaScript,
>   first manipulate the native control, then use the refresh method to
>   tell the enhanced control to update itself to match the new state.
>   Here are some examples of how to update common form controls, then
>   call the refresh method:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

Checkboxes:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Radios:

```
$("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Selects:

```
var myselect = $("#selectfoo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Sliders:

```
$("input[type='range']").val(60).slider("refresh");
```

Flip switches (they use slider):

```
var myswitch = $("#selectbar");
myswitch[0].selectedIndex = 1;
myswitch.slider("refresh");
```

try:

```
$('form').prop('selectedIndex',0);
$('form').trigger('create');
```

Or if this is a drop down select

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/selects/methods.html

JS

```
$('form').prop('selectedIndex',0);
//refresh value         

$('select').selectmenu('refresh');

//refresh and force rebuild 
$('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a change event on the select...call the the change event after you programmaticaly change the index.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a select box like:

```
<select name="opt1">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

You can select the option you want like:

```
$("select").val("3");
```